# How to create a custom NSView for NSSavePanel in Cocoa MacOS objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

[image]

I need to add a save extension selector with a text label next to it to my `NSSavePanel`. In the screenshot attached I try to demonstrate that I succeeded in adding an `NSComboBox` to my panel with the function `setAccessoryView`. However I have no idea how to create a custom NSView, which includes both an `NSComboBox` and an `NSTextView` or equivalent. I found no tutorials on the internet (or if I found one it was extremely outdated) showing how to create custom `NSView`s in objective-C in Cocoa on MacOS.

How can I create a custom `NSView` containing a combobox and a text label? Or how can I add two "stock" `NSView`s to the same `NSSavePanel`? Please be as detailed in your answer as possible, as I have very limited objective-c experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked how to create an `NSView` in Objective-C with an `NSTextField` and an `NSComboBox` as subviews.

Basically, you could define them in Interface Builder and programmatically set the resulting view in Objective-C as the `accessoryView` of the `NSSavePanel`. Alternatively, the custom `NSView` could be created entirely in Objective-C, which is probably the easier option here.

After instantiating an `NSView`, you can use `addSubview:` to add an `NSTextField` and an `NSComboBox` accordingly. Then you can use `NSLayoutConstraints` to set up Auto Layout, which takes care of sizing the `accessoryView` and arranging the subviews properly based on the width of the dialog.

If you create the views programmatically and use Auto Layout, you must explicitly set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Should you want to set the [`allowedContentTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/3566857-allowedcontenttypes?language=objc), a textual mapping of the displayed extension to `UTType` via a `NSDictionary` might be useful.

If you set the delegate of the `NSComboBox` to `self`, then you will be informed about changes of the user selection in the `NSComboBox` via `comboBoxSelectionDidChange:`.

If the things discussed are implemented appropriately in code, it might look something like this for a self-contained example:

```
#import <UniformTypeIdentifiers/UniformTypeIdentifiers.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <NSComboBoxDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSavePanel *savePanel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary<NSString *, UTType*> *typeMapping;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        _typeMapping = @{
            @"jpeg": UTTypeJPEG,
            @"png": UTTypePNG,
            @"tiff": UTTypeTIFF
        };
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSView *)accessoryView {
    NSTextField *label = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"Filetypes:"];
    label.textColor = NSColor.lightGrayColor;
    label.font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:NSFont.smallSystemFontSize];
    label.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    
    NSComboBox *comboBox = [NSComboBox new];
    comboBox.editable = NO;
    for (NSString *extension in self.typeMapping.allKeys) {
        [comboBox addItemWithObjectValue:extension];
    }
    [comboBox setDelegate:self];
    
    NSView *view = [NSView new];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view addSubview:comboBox];
    
    comboBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [label.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.bottomAnchor constant:-12],
        [label.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:64.0],
        [label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],

        [comboBox.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.topAnchor constant:8.0],
        [comboBox.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:label.trailingAnchor constant:8.0],
        [comboBox.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.bottomAnchor constant:-8.0],
        [comboBox.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.trailingAnchor constant:-20.0],
    ]];
    return view;
}

- (void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSComboBox *comboBox = notification.object;
    NSString *selectedItem = comboBox.objectValueOfSelectedItem;
    NSLog(@"### set allowedContentTypes to %@ (%@)", selectedItem, self.typeMapping[selectedItem]);
    [self.savePanel setAllowedContentTypes:@[ self.typeMapping[selectedItem] ]];
}

- (IBAction)onSave:(id)sender {
    NSWindow *window = NSApplication.sharedApplication.windows.firstObject;
    self.savePanel = [NSSavePanel new];
    self.savePanel.accessoryView = [self accessoryView];
    [self.savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse result) {
        if (result != NSModalResponseOK) {
            return;
        }
        NSURL *fileURL = self.savePanel.URL;
        NSLog(@"### selectedFile: %@", fileURL);
    }];
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}

@end
```

Finally, a screenshot of the above demo code in action looks like this:
[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: This amazing, thank you so much! I would have never figured out this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Press Cmd-N to add a new file to your project. Choose a View file to add a xib file that has a custom view.

[image]

Open the xib file and add the controls to the custom view. Press the Add button in the project window toolbar to access the user interface elements.

Use the `NSNib` class to load the xib file and get the custom view.